# Android Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=Take_Message flg=0x10 (has extras) }

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Below there is my `BroadcastReceiver` code where I'm getting this error:

```
 public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
                String username = extra.getString(MessageInfo.USERID);
                String message = extra.getString(MessageInfo.MESSAGETEXT);

                if (username != null && message != null) {
                    if (friend.userName.equals(username)) {
                        myarray.add(username + ":" + "\n" + message);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        localstoragehandler.insert(username,
                                imService.getUsername(), message);

                    } else {
                        if (message.length() > 15) {
                            message = message.substring(0, 15);
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(Messaging.this,
                                username + " says '" + message + "'",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

        };
```

Logcat message :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=Take_Message flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.android.app.Messaging$MessageReceiver@535d151c

Comment: Now try to read your "question" twice and understand that it impossible to answer without reading your thoughts.

Comment: edited please help if can

Comment: Please add the full stack trace. There is more useful data in the logcat, like the actual cause of the problem.